# Change the position of Label by pressing a Button in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to using Tkinter in Python and am working on a Chess project. I have created an 8x8 board using the grid and icons placed as labels for pieces. The blank spaces are also white icons as labels. I need help replacing the initial label with another label when the position of the initial and final row and column are known. The code for this project is quite lengthy and repetitive, so I will not include it here.

```
blackr = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("blackr.png"))
rookb1 = Label(image=blackr)
rookb1.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: You can simply use `.configure()` to change the image or text of a label instead of *replacing* it. Also we don't need your full code, we need a [mre] and state the issue you came across.

Comment: the move is user defined, each square is a different grid piece, let me include something to give reference

Comment: Then you can: 1) call `rookb1.grid(row=target_row, column=target_col)` to move the required label to the required position; 2) remove the original label at target position; 3) create a blank label at the original position of `rookb1`.